# Java - syntax error during tutorial

Tags: java, error-handling

I have the following code:

```
 /* Demonstrate the if.
Call this file IfDemo.java. */

package ifdemo;

public static void main(String args[}) {
    int a,b,c;{
    a=2;
    b=3;

    if (a<b) System.out.println("A is less than B");

    //this won't display anything if (a==b) System.out.println("You won't see this")
    System.out.println();
    c=a-b; // C contains -1
    System.out.println("C contains -1");
    if (C >= 0) system.out.println("C is non-negative");
    if (C < 0) system.out.println("C is negative");

    System.out.println();
    C=b-a; //C contains 1 
    System.out.println("C contains 1");
    if (C >=0)System.out.println("C is non-negative");
    if (C<0)System.out.println("C is negative");

}}
```

At the line: public static void main(String args[} ) {
I get three errors:
1.Syntax error on token "void" , @ expected
2.Syntax error on tokens, classheader expected instead
3.Syntax error on tokens, misplaced constructs

I hope you guys can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be careful with the case of variables in Java. It's `if (c >= 0)` etc. Also encapsulate the code in a class

Comment: Please click [edit] and post your modified code after the update.

Answer (score 1):

In Java there are no free-standing functions, you are missing a class declaration outside of your `main` function. Here is how the structure of your code should look:

```
package ifdemo;

public class IfDemo { // <<== You are missing this line

    public static void main(String args[]) { // <<== You have a typo here
        .... //                         ^
        .... //           This should be a square bracket
    }

}
```

Also watch out for "stray" curly braces throughout your code: it is very important to have your braces balanced, otherwise the program will not compile with very strange errors.

Comment: OK thanks. I editted the code but I stil have one error: "The public type ifdemo must be defined in its own file"

Comment: @mm1985 Please edit the question and post your updated code, preferably in a separate block of code. Click the "edit" link under your question to enter the edit mode.

Comment: @mm1985 "The public type ifdemo must be defined in its own file" means that your file name is not "ifdemo.java". Make sure the file name and the class name match

Comment: @mm1985 You need to call your file `IfDemo.java`

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing the bracket:

...
public static void main(String args[])
...

Answer (score 0):

You have written `}` instead of `]`

`public static void main(String args[]) {`

Answer (score 0):

Class is missing,Behind int a,b,c; you have brace... you have to remove it and String should be (String[]args)

Comment: actually, this part is fine. Useless, but fine.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `String args[]` and not `String args[}`. Or even better: `String[] args`, which makes it clearer that `args` is a variable of type String array.

And the main method should be inside a class named `IfDemo`. You can't just declare methods outside of a class.

Also, Java is case sensitive `C` and `c` are not the same thing. `System` and `system` are not the same thing.

Comment: Suprised that you missed the missing class. ;) Well, there are hell lot of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be inside a class. Your file name suggests it should be

```
public class IFDemo {
```

I suggest you use an IDE to help you write the code.  This will ensure you don't get so far with basic pieces of code missing/incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {   //Its [] and not [}

        int a,b,c;

        a=2;
        b=3;

        if (a<b) System.out.println("A is less than B");


        System.out.println();
        c=a-b; // C contains -1
        System.out.println("C contains -1");
        if (c >= 0)    // Its not capital C . Its small c
            System.out.println("C is non-negative");   // Its capital S and not small s
        if (c < 0)
              System.out.println("C is negative");

        System.out.println();
        c=b-a; //C contains 1   // Its Capital 
        System.out.println("C contains 1");
        if (c >=0)System.out.println("C is non-negative");
        if (c<0)System.out.println("C is negative");

    }
```